# How to use Morton Order(z order curve) in range search?

Tags: z-order-curve

How to use Morton Order in range search?
From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), In the paragraph "Use with one-dimensional data structures for range searching",

it says

> "the range being queried (x = 2, ..., 3, y = 2, ..., 6) is indicated
>   by the dotted rectangle. Its highest Z-value (MAX) is 45. In this
>   example, the value F = 19 is encountered when searching a data
>   structure in increasing Z-value direction. ......BIGMIN (36 in the
>   example).....only search in the interval between BIGMIN and MAX...."

My questions are:

1) why the **F** is 19? Why the **F** should not be 16?

2) How to get the **BIGMIN**?

3) Are there any web blogs demonstrate how to do the range search?

Comment: Potentially helpful application with DynamoDB: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** The AWS Database Blog now has [a detailed introduction to this subject](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-1/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=zackblog&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&sc_category=rds&sc_outcome=aware&adbsc=awsdbblog_social_20170517_72417147&adbid=864895517733470208&adbpl=tw&adbpr=66780587).

---

[This blog post](http://docs.raima.com/rdme/9_1/Content/GS/POIexample.htm) does a reasonable job of illustrating the process.

When searching the rectangular space `x=[2,3], y=[2,6]`:

1. The minimum Z Value (12) is found by interleaving the bits of the lowest `x` and `y` values:  2 and 2, respectively.
2. The maximum Z value (45) is found by interleaving the bits of the highest `x` and `y` values: 3 and 6, respectively.
3. Having found the min and max Z values (12 and 45), we now have a linear range that we can iterate across that is guaranteed to contain all of the entries inside of our rectangular space. The data within the linear range is going to be a **superset** of the data we actually care about: the data in the rectangular space. If we simply iterate across the entire range, we are going to find all of the data we care about and then some. You can test each value you visit to see if it's relevant or not.

An obvious optimization is to try to minimize the amount of superfluous data that you must traverse. This is largely a function of the number of 'seams' that you cross in the data -- places where the 'Z' curve has to make large jumps to continue its path (e.g. from Z value 31 to 32 below).

[image: Z Order Curve range traversal]

This can be mitigated by employing the `BIGMIN` and `LITMAX` functions to identify these seams and navigate back to the rectangle. To minimize the amount of irrelevant data we evaluate, we can:

1. Keep a count of the number of consecutive pieces of junk data we've visited.
2. Decide on a maximum allowable value (`maxConsecutiveJunkData`) for this count. The blog post linked at the top uses `3` for this value.
3. If we encounter `maxConsecutiveJunkData` pieces of irrelevant data in a row, we initiate `BIGMIN` and `LITMAX`. Importantly, at the point at which we've decided to use them, we're now somewhere within our linear search space (Z values 12 to 45) but **outside** the rectangular search space. In the Wikipedia article, they appear to have chosen a `maxConsecutiveJunkData` value of `4`; they started at Z=12 and walked until they were 4 values outside of the rectangle (beyond 15) before deciding that it was now time to use `BIGMIN`. Because `maxConsecutiveJunkData` is left to your tastes, `BIGMIN` can be used on any value in the linear range (Z values 12 to 45). Somewhat confusingly, the article only shows the area from 19 on as crosshatched because that is the subrange of the search that will be optimized out when we use `BIGMIN` with a `maxConsecutiveJunkData` of 4.

When we realize that we've wandered outside of the rectangle too far, we can conclude that the rectangle in non-contiguous. `BIGMIN` and `LITMAX` are used to identify the nature of the split. `BIGMIN` is designed to, given any value in the linear search space (e.g. 19), find the next smallest value that will be back inside the half of the split rectangle with larger Z values (i.e. jumping us from 19 to 36). `LITMAX` is similar, helping us to find the largest value that will be inside the half of the split rectangle with smaller Z values. The implementations of `BIGMIN` and `LITMAX` are explained in depth in the [`zdivide`](http://docs.raima.com/rdme/9_1/Content/GS/POIexample.htm#zdivide) function explanation in the linked blog post.

Comment: The link to raima.com has gone bad. It can be found on the WayBack Machine at https://web.archive.org/web/20180311015006/https://docs.raima.com/rdme/9_1/Content/GS/POIexample.htm.

Comment: See also this [relevant paper](https://www.vision-tools.com/h-tropf/multidimensionalrangequery.pdf), which might be the basis for those other sources. It's pretty readable.

Comment: Another good link, still active on raima.com (but different content from the one linked above): https://raima.com/wp-content/uploads/COTS_embedded_database_solving_dynamic_pois_2012.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the quoted example in the Wikipedia article has not been edited to clarify the context and assumptions. The approach used in that example is applicable to linear data structures that only allow sequential (forward and backward) seeking; that is, it is assumed that one cannot randomly seek to a storage cell in constant time using its morton index alone.

With that constraint, one's strategy begins with a full range that is the mininum morton index (16) and the maximum morton index (45). To make optimizations, one tries to find and eliminate large swaths of subranges that are outside the query rectangle. The hatched area in the diagram refers to what would have been accessed (sequentially) if such optimization (eliminating subranges) had not been applied.

After discussing the main optimization strategy for linear sequential data structures, it goes on to talk about other data structures with better seeking capability.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to to 'How'. Are there any web blogs demonstrate how to do the range search in detail?